# issue while uploading a file using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload file mainly images using ajax and php but not able to retrieve the image at the php side.

**HTML code** :

```
<input type='file' name='LogoImageUploader' id='LogoImageUploader' onchange='FileUploadCheck();' />
```

**ajax call** :

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('#LogoImageUploader')[0].files[0]);
  jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",       
          url: "FileUploadChecker.php",      
         data: formData,
          processData: false, 
          contentType: false,
          async: false,
          cache: false,
          success : function(result){
              alert(result);
          }
        });
}
```

and then the **php code**, here i am unable to retrieve image :

`echo basename($_FILES['LogoImageUploader']['name']);`

the ajax call results in following payload request :

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryb3jaGq8f7FbEKHF7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryb3jaGq8f7FbEKHF7--
```

when i did `var_dump($_FILES)` in my php file the response that i get of the ajax call is

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending image by name `file` so use

```
 $_FILES['file']
```

Instead of

```
 $_FILES['LogoImageUploader']
```

Or change in js

```
 formData.append('LogoImageUploader', $('#LogoImageUploader')[0].files[0]);
```

Comment: that didnt work... do i need to add anything in the php file before that ? right now it just as `<?php
echo $_FILES['file']; ?>`

Comment: thanks a lot buddy. that worked. i figured out i need to add this to my php code file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump($_FILES);